# Keeping call open

Tags: vxml, voicexml

I'm trying to create sort of listener. I need voice xml that will keep the call open and not hang up. I tried to do that with  tag, but max i can get is 2 minutes. Is there some sleep or loop tags with time out I can use?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at VoiceXML's close cousin [Call Control XML (CCXML)](http://www.w3.org/TR/ccxml/).  CCXML provide more call control (as the name implies) and allows you to kick off VoiceXML sessions from it.  It can monitor the call for the duration.  What are you listening for?  If you provide more information on what your solution is supposed to do I may be able to provide more specific guidance.